# PowerShell: unable to get the open property of the workbooks class

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell

So I try to open an Excel file with PowerShell. But I got this error message: "unable to get the open property of the workbooks class".

```
$dirPath = ("C:\Users\localadmin\OneDrive\DailyReports\")
$manFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath -Recurse -Filter "*MANSUM*"
$manPath = $manFile.Fullname
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$manWB = $excel.Workbooks.Open($manPath)
```

How can I fix this error?

The full path (`$manPath`) is correct.

Running Windows 10 Pro, Excel 2016

Comment: One thing I noticed when I tested is the filter for the file names in the `Get-ChildItem` needs to point to excel files specifically so try `$manFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath -Recurse -Filter "*MANSUM*.xlsx"` for example and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution:

Need to create folder and provide proper access rights.

・Windows 2008 Server x64

Please make this folder.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

・Windows 2008 Server x86

Please make this folder.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Refer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64?forum=innovateonoffice

Comment: This is only marginally valid when running under the SYSTEM context.